# Pandas - adding another column with the same name as another column

Tags: python, pandas

for example see below:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | X | X |  |
| X | X | X | X |
| X |  |  |  |
| X | X |  |  |
| X | X | X | X |
| X | X | X | X |
| X |  |  |  |

how would I add another column with a 4 in it? I have used:

df = df.assign(4 = np.zeros(shape=(df.shape[0],1))

however, it just changes the columns of 4 to what I have entered.

I hope this question is clear enough! Future state should look like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | X | X |  |  |
| X | X | X | X |  |
| X |  |  |  |  |
| X | X |  |  |  |
| X | X | X | X |  |
| X | X | X | X |  |
| X |  |  |  |  |

Comment: that's a bad idea

Comment: Could you clarify why you need another identically named column? Typically you wouldn’t want to have columns with the same name.

Comment: Its too much detail to get into but essentially I need it for a parser im creating. the export spits out the data vertically and i need to put it hozirontally. for example, the column headers are: ID - Name - Phone # - Email - Name - Phone # - Email over and over, but for some reason it ends with Phone # and not email. so one entry has 1 less column. I want to add a null column and run my parser so when i turn it into a DF it has the same level of rows / columns to concatenate it

Answer (score 2):

As @anon01 states, this is not a good idea, but you can use `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(-1, 5))
pd.concat([df,pd.Series([np.nan]*5).rename(4)], axis=1)
```

And as @CameronRiddell states:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.Series(np.nan, name=4)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   4
0   0   1   2   3   4 NaN
1   5   6   7   8   9 NaN
2  10  11  12  13  14 NaN
3  15  16  17  18  19 NaN
4  20  21  22  23  24 NaN
```

Comment: fun side note: swapping `pd.Series([np.nan]*5)` for `pd.Series(np.nan)` works and will broadcast that Series to the same length as the dataframe you're concatenating it to. So you can rewrite that second line to `pd.concat([df, pd.Series(np.nan, name=4)], axis=1)`

Comment: Cheeky... it's what I do: `df.assign(a=np.nan).rename(columns={'a': 4})`

Comment: @CameronRiddell you have to commit to the ridiculousness `df.T.append(pd.Series(np.nan, name=4)).T`